# Moving android layouts

Tags: android

I have an app bar at the top of the screen, and I have a linear layout with two buttons and a textView. This linear layout is inside of the toolbar and I cant figure out why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.stuff.stuff.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:id="@+id/leftDateButton"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/dateBox"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:id="@+id/rightDateButton"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="563dp"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

You can see the two arrows in the bar at the top. I am trying to get those just below the bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to the linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Enclose all the layout items after the **AppBarLayout** element inside a

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior>
     <LinearLayout
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:paddingLeft="40dp"
         android:paddingRight="40dp"
         android:paddingTop="10dp"
         android:paddingBottom="10dp"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
    android:id="@+id/leftDateButton"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/dateBox"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:id="@+id/rightDateButton"
    />
     </LinearLayout>

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="563dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
           </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I get Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child.

Comment: Put the view pager and the linear layout in a parent linear layout, I will update my answer